# Deploying background worker for rails like Resque into CloudFoundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud-foundry

Currently working on building a live dashboard with Rails which needs a background processing to keep polling for data every now and then to keep the dashboard afresh. I am able to achieve that with Resque, Resque-Scheduler and Redis Server and works fine **locally**. All the code is baked into Rails app, for example, if user visits the dashboard page, inside the dashboard_controller I queue the job like this

```
Resque.enqueue(BackgroundJob, params)
```

And I have the worker performing the job from **app/worker/background_job.rb**

```
class BackgroundJob
  @queue = :backgroundq

  def self.perform
    < PERFORM CODE HERE>
  end
end
```

**Problem:**

When I had to deploy into Cloudfoundry it instructs me to deploy the same code twice in different names 1. as a Rails app (Web Process) 2. as a Ruby no-route app for the background worker binding to the same Redis service on the cloud. I dont understand the process here, if they live in  two different app spaces and how they communicate to each other ? because I need to communicate lots of data back and forth. For sure I am lacking some basic application architecture design. Can someone explain how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you miss something because rails app and worker it's different process. When you call `Resque.enqueue(BackgroundJob, params)` you communicate with worker via redis. So if you want to communicate back you must use something like redis or postgres or event text file.

Can you get more information about your task?

Comment: Thank you Arsen ! So if they are a different processes, then is it advisable to separate the worker logic and deploy as  another app? and Rails app will use Resque to enqueue the job which will go to Redis and Worker keep looking at Redis to look for a new job? am i right?

Comment: @Krish hm... no you don't need to make two different apps think about like it's two different mode of one app. Yes, worker is looking for tasks at redis. You're right!

Comment: More info on the Task: Its polling a REST API endpoint every 30 seconds or so for a JSON data and send it back to the RAILS app which renders the graph on the UI with that json data. UI might contain multiple graphs in one single page, so multiple concurrent jobs polling for data to keep those graph component afresh until user closes or move away from the dashboard page.

Comment: @Krish I'd recommend run a worker. When worker got a data just put it in a database. And rails app can read it and send to client.

Comment: Thanks for promptly jumping in and helping me out ! I really appreciate your time in helping me ! sighhh what a relief !

Comment: @Krish not a problem :)